# "Dropdown-Menu" closing when trying to open children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

My problem is quite strange but I will try to explain as clear as I can.
So I made a webshop, with main category "menu" on the home page.

It's a kinda "dropdown menu", because when you hover on a sub-category it shows the sub-sub-categories and so on.

However the problem is that when I hover on the sub-categories and it shows the sub-sub-categores it is closing as soon as I try to click on a category.
Is it possible to keep it open while my mouse is in the "li" element of the category?
Some code snippets:

So I have ul -> li -> a in every sub-menu

```
.box .box-content .box-category .nav_sub_submenu ul li a:hover + .nav_submenu_test {

          ...
          visibility: visible;
          ... 
}
```

So this makes the sub-menu visible when I hover the "a" element. And I want it to keep opened while my mouse is inside the "li" where the given "a" is.
Hope you understood my problem, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide complete code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the hover element on the `a` tag instead of the `li`.

You made need to change the `+` to a `>` to target the inner list as well.

Change:
`.box .box-content .box-category .nav_sub_submenu ul li a:hover + .nav_submenu_test`

To:
`.box .box-content .box-category .nav_sub_submenu ul li:hover > .nav_submenu_test`

Comment: God, you can't imagine how much time I've spent figuring this out. :)
Thanks a lot Sir.